# python convert unicode to string

Tags: python, database

I got my results from sqlite by python, it's like this kind of tuples: (u'PR:000017512',)
However, I wanna print it as 'PR:000017512'. At first, I tried to select the first one in tuple by using index [0]. But the print out results is still u'PR:000017512'. Then I used str() to convert and nothing changed. How can I print this without u''?

Answer (score 8):

You're confusing the string *representation* with its value. When you print a unicode string the `u` doesn't get printed:

```
>>> foo=u'abc'
>>> foo
u'abc'
>>> print foo
abc
```

#### Update:

Since you're dealing with a tuple, you don't get off this easy: You have to print the *members* of the tuple:

```
>>> foo=(u'abc',)
>>> print foo
(u'abc',)
>>> # If the tuple really only has one member, you can just subscript it:
>>> print foo[0]
abc
>>> # Join is a more realistic approach when dealing with iterables:
>>> print '\n'.join(foo)
abc
```

Comment: But when I append these results to a list and print the list, the u still exists

Comment: printing a list prints the `repr` of each member.

Answer (score 2):

Don't see the problem:

```
>>> x = (u'PR:000017512',)
>>> print x
(u'PR:000017512',)
>>> print x[0]
PR:000017512
>>>
```

You the string is in unicode format, but it still means PR:000017512

Check out the docs on String literals

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 1):

```
In [22]: unicode('foo').encode('ascii','replace') 
Out[22]: 'foo'
```

Comment: not sure why you got a downvote ... I think this technically answers OP's question ... even though probably not his intent