# Printing a string prints 'u' before the string in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, printing, python-2.x

'u' before elements in printed list? I didn't type u in my code.

```
hobbies = []

#prompt user three times for hobbies
for i in range(3):
    hobby = raw_input('Enter a hobby:')
    hobbies.append(hobby)

#print list stored in hobbies
print hobbies
```

When I run this, it prints the list but it is formatted like this:

```
Enter a hobby: Painting
Enter a hobby: Stargazing
Enter a hobby: Reading
[u'Painting', u'Stargazing', u'Reading']
None
```

Where did those 'u' come from before each of the elements of the list?

Comment: `u` represents a unicode string. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-remove-the-u-as-in-unicode-in-usomestring

Comment: Try reading this http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: The `u` is no more a part of the string itself than the `'` characters are. The actual string is `Painting`, not `u'Painting'` or `'Painting'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python convert unicode to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819848/python-convert-unicode-to-string)

Comment: @kojiro my question was more on 'why' there is 'u'..

Comment: @Lotus92 Having carefully looked at the questions, I still am of the opinion they are "the same" question. They're phrased differently, but I think they come from the same understanding of Python and `repr`s.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you're actually surprised by here is that printing a single string doesn't do the same thing as printing a list of strings—and this is true whether they're Unicode or not:

```
>>> hobby1 = u'Dizziness'
>>> hobby2 = u'Vértigo'
>>> hobbies = [hobby1, hobby2]
>>> print hobby1
Dizziness
>>> print hobbies
[u'Dizziness', u'V\xe9rtigo']
```

Even without the `u`, you've got those extra quotes, not to mention that backslash escape. And if you try the same thing with `str` byte strings instead of `unicode` strings, you'll still have the quotes and escapes (plus you might have mojibake characters if your source file and your terminal have different encodings… but forget that part).

---

In Python, every object can have two different representations: the end-user-friendly representation, `str`, and the programmer-friendly representation, `repr`. For byte strings, those representations are `Painting` and `'Painting'`, respectively. And for Unicode strings, they're `Painting` and `u'Painting'`.

The `print` statement uses the `str`, so `print hobby1` prints out `Painting`, with no quotes (or `u`, if it's Unicode).

However, the `str` of a list uses the `repr` of each of its elements, not the `str`. So, when you print `hobbies`, each element has quotes around it (and a `u` if it's Unicode).

This may seem weird at first, but it's an intentional design decision, and it makes sense once you get used to it. And it would be ambiguous to print out `[foo, bar, baz]`—is that a list of three strings, or a list of two strings, one of which has a comma in the middle of it? But, more importantly, a list is *already* not a user-friendly thing, no matter how you print it out. `My hobbies are [Painting, Stargazing]` would look just as ugly as `My hobbies are ['Painting', 'Stargazing']`. When you want to show a list to an end-user, you always want to format it explicitly in some way that makes sense.

Often, what you want is as simple as this:

```
>>> print 'Hobbies:', ', '.join(hobbies)
Hobbies: Painting, Stargazing
```

Or, for Unicode strings:

```
>>> print u'Hobbies:', u', '.join(hobbies)
Hobbies: Painting, Stargazing
```

Comment: You must be the fastest typist ever!  The last five questions I looked at all had long answers like this one!

Comment: Perfect. Just the answer i was looking for!

Comment: @SethMMorton: I am a pretty fast typist. But also, whenever I have to wait for a compile or a test to run or something else that takes long enough to be annoying, but not long enough to answer a new question or play a quick game or take a break, I tend to go back and re-edit the answer sitting in front of me. If SO showed complete edit history instead of collapsed, you'd be surprised…

Answer (score 7):

The 'u' is not part of the string, but indicates that the string is a unicode string.

Answer (score 6):

You're not printing the strings, you're printing the representation of the list holding the strings.

```
for hobby in hobbies:
  print hobby
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the unicode to string. You can simply use
str(unicodedString) or unicode(normalString) for the other way conversion

**Code**

```
hobbies = []

#prompt user three times for hobbies
for i in range(3):
    hobby = raw_input('Enter a hobby:')
    # converting the normal string to unicode
    hobbies.append(unicode(hobby))

# Printing the unicoded string
print("Unicoded string")
print(hobbies)
hobbies = [str(items) for items in hobbies]

# Printing the converted string
print("Normal string from unicoded string")
print(hobbies)
```

**Output**

```
Enter a hobby:test1
Enter a hobby:Test2
Enter a hobby:Test3

Unicoded string
[u'test1', u'Test2', u'Test3']

Normal string from unicoded string
['test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
```