# print arabic words and list in python 2.7

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, arabic

I am using anaconda Python 2.7 for Arabic text classification 
when I print words or list or words it appears in Unicode
I want to print the real Arabic words
the list contians [Arabic sentence, label]

> ```
> from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
> reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('mypath\\', r'(\w+)\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(\w+)\.txt',encoding='utf-8')
> document=reader.words('fileid')
> ```
>
> documen[0]

output

> [[u'\u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633',
>   u'\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0646', ...],  'Politic']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing a string prints 'u' before the string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170808/printing-a-string-prints-u-before-the-string-in-python)

Comment: Did you try `print`?

Comment: yes print gives the same results

Comment: Could it be that your console doesn't support unicode? What does `print u'\u0631'` return? Is it `ر` or is it `u'\u0631'`?

Comment: it works will with single Arabic sentence. print ر

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. `print [u'\u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633']` yields the unicode control codes. Interestingly, it seems to output the Arabic characters when run under python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd assume this is because Python 2.7  was written under ASCII focus (as such, `str(u'\u0631')` yields a `UnicodeEncodeError`, as the ر character doesn't exist in ASCII. `print u'\u0631'` probably works because it's simply sending the unicode straight to the console, which is equipped to handle unicode rendering.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way Python 2 works when you print lists.  Print the individual strings or update to Python 3:

**Python 2**

```
>>> s = [[u'\u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633', u'\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0646'], 'Politic']
>>> print s
[[u'\u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633', u'\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0646'], 'Politic']
>>> print s[0][0]
رئيس
>>> print s[0][1]
البرلمان
```

**Python 3**

```
>>> s = [[u'\u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633', u'\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0646'], 'Politic']
>>> print(s)
[['رئيس', 'البرلمان'], 'Politic']
>>> print(s[0][0])
رئيس
>>> print(s[0][1])
البرلمان
```

You get the old behavior with `ascii()` in Python 3:

```
>>> print(ascii(s))
[['\u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633', '\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0646'], 'Politic']
```